# Prove that two elements of $A$ should differ by 3.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ consist of $16$ elements of the set $\{1,2,3,...,106\}$ so that no two element differ by $6,9,12,15,18$ or $21$. Prove that two elements of $A$ should differ by 3.

Comment: Source of this problem, please?

Comment: just a note, which may be relevant - the problem is not changed by subtracting $1$ from each element of $\{1,2,3,...,106\}$, so then, except for $105$ we can write the numbers in $A$ as $3a_i+b_i$ with $a_i \in \{0,...,34\}$ and $b_i \in \{0,1,2\}$

Answer (score 4):

Let us separate the set $U=\{1,2,\cdots,106\}$ into $5$ 'rooms' as
$$\{1,2,\cdots,22\},\{23,24,\cdots,44\},\{45,46,\cdots,66\},\{67,68,\cdots,88\},\{89,90,\cdots,106\}$$
Note that each of the first four rooms has $22$ elements and that the last room has $18$ elements.

Now, since we choose $16$ elements from the set $U$, at least some $4$ elements have to be chosen from either one of the five rooms.

We may suppose that we choose $4$ elements from the set $\{1,2,\cdots,22\}$. Considering in mod $3$, we have to choose some $2$ elements which are congruent in mod $3$. The difference between the two elements is $3$. **Q.E.D.**

Comment: Isn't it if two elements are congruent in mod $3$ their difference is $3k$ not $3$?

Comment: @kingW3: The difference has to be $3$ because the difference between any two of the four elemets is neither $6,9,12,15,18,21$.

Comment: Could you state the principle of Pigeonhole in devising the strategy as it directly uses the principle and further the question should state that atleast two of the numbers of the 16 differ by 3. Will you not agree?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A$ has no two points differing by $3$. Let $C = \{0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21\}$.
Consider the sets of the form $i + 24j + C$ for $i=1,2,3$, and $j=0,\dots,4$. There are $15$ of them. They are disjoint. Their union is $\{1,2,\dots,120\}$. And each one can contain at most one element from $A$.

This proof shows that $A$ can be allowed to contain elements up to $120$, not just $106$.